# Paypal | Can I accept credit card payments using Paypal

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am trying to integrate Paypal REST SDK where user is redirected to Paypal website for payment and returns after success(or failure). The [documentation page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/) says(in red box)
that "use of PayPal REST is restricted for credit cards" [image]

On reading [online discussions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/14), somewhere it is mentioned that "direct credit cards" can't be accepted. Firstly, what is "direct credit card"? Then is it true that normal credit cards can pay via this SDK. Also, does direct credit card holders can pay via normal route too.

Note: I can't use Braintree Direct as advised in docs as it is still not available in India

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the above question is called PayPal Guest Checkout.

**Guest Checkout** [hosted checkout solution on PayPal servers] is an option for buyers who don't have PayPal Account but can make a Payment using Credit Card which will redirect them to the PayPal website.

**FLOW:** 
Checkout Page -> Checkout with PP(PayPal) -> No PP Account -> Guest Checkout -> Use Credit Card for Payment.

This is how Guest Checkout looks like.
[Guest Checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyu6Z.png)

**Direct Credit Card[DCC]:** It is seamless checkout using Credit Card on the website without being redirected to PayPal.

**FLOW:**
Checkout Page -> Select Pay using Credit Card -> Enter Card Details -> Submit

Here is how the DCC looks like.
[Direct Credit Card Payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ObuN.png)

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

## Card Payment with Paypal

## step-1 Add card Details

```
    from paypalrestsdk import CreditCard
    from paypalrestsdk import Payment

    def card_payemnt(request):
        paypalrestsdk.configure({
            "mode": "sandbox",  # sandbox or live
            'client_id' :"",
            'client_secret':"",
        })

        credit_card = CreditCard({
            "type": "visa",
            "number": "4024007185826731",
            "expire_month": "12",
            "expire_year": "2022",
            "cvv2": "874",
            "first_name": "Joe",
            "last_name": "Shopper",
        })

        if credit_card.create():
            print("CreditCard[%s] created successfully" % (credit_card.id ))
            return HttpResponse('good')
        else:
            print("Error while creating CreditCard:")
            print(credit_card.error)
```

## step2 Complete Payment by using Card ID

```
        def credit_card_payment(request):
            paypalrestsdk.configure({
                "mode": "sandbox",  # sandbox or live
                'client_id': "",
                'client_secret': "",
            })
            payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment(
                {
                    "intent": "sale",
                    "payer": {
                        "payment_method": "credit_card",
                        "funding_instruments": [
                            {
                                "credit_card_token": {
                                    "credit_card_id": "CARD-7MH68586JW7132142LXWASJI",

                                }
                            }]
                    },
                    "transactions": [
                        {
                            "amount": {
                                "total": "6.70",
                                "currency": "USD"
                            },
                            "description": "Payment by vaulted credit card."
                        }]
                }
            )
            if payment.create():
                print(payment.id)

                print("Payment created successfully")
            else:
                print(payment.error)
```